# What does the brace mean?

Tags: php

```
class Util_Model
{
/**
 * Get model property by property name chain.
 * Usage: Util_Model::get_prop($order, 'item', 'name')
 */
public static function get_prop()
{
    $obj  = func_get_arg(0);
    $props = array_slice(func_get_args(), 1);

    if (!is_object($obj)) {
        throw new \InvalidArgumentException('First parameter must be an object');
    }

    foreach ($props as $prop) {
        if (preg_match('/^(.*)\(\)$/', $prop, $matches)) {
            $obj = call_user_func(array($obj, $matches[1]));
        } else {
            $obj = $obj->{$prop};
        }
        if (!is_object($obj)) {
            break;
        }
    }

    return is_object($obj) ? (string)$obj : $obj;
}
}
```

**$obj->{$prop}** i wonder the meaning of this line, why there is a brace here? and why there is no error when **{$prop}** is null.if you don't understand my question, leave something I will amend it.thanks!

Comment: check the _variable variables_ manual page on php.net. `$obj->{$prop}` is accessing a property of `$obj` using the _value_ of `$prop` as the name. The brackets aren't required here, but they're recommended to avoid ambiguity when using arrays: `$obj->{$array['key']}` is not the same as `$obj->{$array}['key']`)

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

Answer (score 2):

**$obj->{$prop}** means that `$obj` is trying to access a property whose name is present in the variable `$prop`. I'll explain with an example

```
class A {
     public $d;
     public $e;
     public $f;
     function X() {}
     function Y() {}
     function Z() {}
}

$obj = new A();
$prop = 'X';
$propVar = 'f';
$obj->{$prop}();
$obj->{$propVar};
```

In the above code, `$prop` contains the value 'X', so function X will be invoked, likewise if it was containing values 'Y' or 'Z', they would be invoked. So the invocation of function can be decided at runtime depending on the value the variable contains.

As for the case when `$prop` is null, no object is being accessed, so the reference of object is returned instead and no error is thrown.

Comment: Your code will ***Not*** invoke method `X`!, it'll try to access a non-existent `$X` property. To invoke a method using a variable, you'll have to write `$obj->{$var}();`. Either way, using variables for method invocation is dangerous.

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem, your observation was correct and I have corrected my code accordingly....

Answer (score 1):

It's the preferred syntax when using [Variable Variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) when accessing object properties. In this example, the brackets aren't required, though. Their main purpose is to avoid ambiguity:

```
$obj = (object) array(
    'foo' => array('key' => 123)
);
$access = array('key' => 'foo');
var_dump($obj->{$access['key']});//will dump array(key => 123)
var_dump($obj->$access['key']);//ambiguous
```

The latter is ambiguous, because PHP might take the statement to mean *"convert `$access` to its string value (which is Array), access the property with that name, and get the index `key` from that value"*, or it could mean, access the property with the name you find under `$access['key']`.

Either way, this *can* be useful, your code is taking it too far. You calling methods like this is *not* a good idea.
A valid use-case could be when dealing with JSON encoded data, or a parsed XML DOM, where there are numeric keys, or keys like `foo-bar`, you can't write:

```
$obj->123;
$obj->foo-bar;//- is invalid
```

For these cases, you use the variable variable notation:

```
$keys = [123, 'foo-bar'];
foreach ($keys as $key)
    echo $obj->{$key}, PHP_EOL;
```